# как узнать с помощью JS сколько блоков DIV в одном ряду экрана браузера и соответственно присвоить им различные классы

Tags: javascript

имееться в наличии разметка html:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
            <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
```

при изменении размера экрана количество блоков разниться в горизонтальном ряду от 1 до 4, как присвоить разные классы в зависимости от количества блоков в ряду. например если 1 блок помещаеться на малом экране или сильно сжатом браузере,
 то добавить класс "a1", а следующий в втором ряду "a2",
 если 2 блока "a1" и "a2",
 если 3 блока то "a1" "a3" "a2",
 а если умещаеться 4 блока то "a1" "a3" "a3" "a2".
количество блоков может быть разным.
желательно реализация через массивы и индексы( все див с класоом "block" в первый массив, а дальше создавать другие массивы в зависимости от размера браузера-ширины и присваивать им различные классы, требуеться проверка если измениться ширина экрана через 2 сек. плавно(блоки стали невидимы, а потом плавно же стали видимы) заново переназначить классы)- это затея для различных анимации появления блоков при скроллинге( например "a1" это появление блока слева(прелоадер wow.js-(очень жаль что у этого прелоадера анимация при скроллинге происходит раз а потом при прокрутке невозвращаеться-непойму что подправить), "a3"- появление справа, и "a3"- плавное появление центрального или двух блоков. желательно 2 варианта- первый старым способом а второй используя последнии навороты js[image: расположение блоков на различных экранов] чуть незабыл- начальное расположение блоков прописано в media.css .

Comment: Можете узнать ширину родительского блока, затем вычислите ширину отдельного блока. Делим ширину родителя на ширину блока, получим в результате сколько блоков можем поместить в ряд

Comment: я понял так можно-но лучше все же проверка сколько блоков с классом в ряду в момент открытия сайта и при изменении размера браузера а потом уже по массивам раскидывать и давать классы- так проще для дальнейших манипуляций адаптивности, чем для каждой проблемы делать заплатки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не хотите это сделать на `CSS`?
Я это делаю таким образом:
Делаю флексовый контейнер, кладу туда элементы, элементам задаю:

```css
.block__flex {
    width: calc(100%/4 - 30px/4);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.block__flex:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Я указываю, что я хочу, чтобы у элемента была ширина 1/4, так как хочу вместить на широкий экран по 4 элемента. Также я задаю всем элементам справа отступ в `10px`, а всем четвёртым элементам обнуляю оступы.
Что я делаю в медиа-запросах:
В каждой линии будет находится по **три** элемента, поэтому ширина элемента будет равна `100%/3`. У четвёртого элемента прошлыми стилями был задан отступ справа нулевой, поэтому пишем, что у него отступ 10px, а **третьему** элементу обнуляем отступ, а из ширины элемента вычитаем `20px/3`. Делим на `три`, для того, чтобы вычитание этих 20px равномерно распределить между **3** элемента.
Дальше тоже я написал медиазапросы, для того, чтобы выстроить элементы в две колонки и в одну. Логика для двух колонок такая же, а для одной колонки я просто задал ширину 100% и полностью обнулил все отступы справа.

```css
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .block__flex {
        width: calc(100%/3 - 20px/3);
    }

    .block__flex:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .block__flex:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

}
```

Это возможно сделать на гридах намного легче, но я их пока не изучал.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block__flex {
  width: calc(100%/4 - 30px/4);
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block__flex:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .block__flex {
    width: calc(100%/3 - 20px/3);
  }
  .block__flex:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .block__flex:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
  .block__flex {
    width: calc(100%/2 - 10px/2);
  }
  .block__flex:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .block__flex:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .block__flex {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .block__flex:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
  <div class="block__flex">
    Здесь находится контент
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: очень неплохо- чтот в инете подругому рисуют- мож ваша реализация покруче будет- над потестировать однако, спасиб.

Comment: отлично все работает лучше у меня)- тут ненад ловить ресайзы), теперь на одну проблему меньше, теперь буду применять разные анимации появления блоков в зависимости от расположения.

Comment: @Дмитрий, если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его как ответ, галочка, возле голосов